# How do I get the column following a particular column?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a column and I'd like to get the column following that particular column.

```
nhood,column,variablecolumn
Treasure Island,3,5
McLaren Park,1,2
Tenderloin,28,112
Lakeshore,14,8
Chinatown,15,103
```

I know the name of the second column, but in my dataset the name of the third column changes.

I tried variants on this idea. I'm trying to get the number "5" from the first row.

```
parseFloat(data[1]["column"+1]);
parseFloat(data[1]["column"]+1);
```

Another idea is to create an array with the column names, pull the index for "column" and then use `index + 1` when I pull the data in that particular command.

Comment: Can you provide some more context and code? Is that CSV read in `d3.csv()`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Like mentioned, you can turn the column names into an array and then pull the index for a particular array. In this case, you can use col as a stand-in for the `variablecolumn` name.

```
var valueKey = data.columns;
var col = valueKey[valueKey.indexOf(dataset)+1];
```